# Css :focus-within on input

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to change the background color among other things when my input has focus
but I'm not getting it I saw that this is possible with: focuswithin

I didn't want to have to make a javascript code for that
but I'm not able to apply the focus: within

code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Styled.SearchWrapper>
      <div className="collapse">
        <div className="iconWrap">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="searchIcon" icon={faCoffee} />
        </div>
        <input
          className="searchBox"
          type="search"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Search..."
        />
      </div>
    </Styled.SearchWrapper>
  );
}
```

css:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const FlexCotainer = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const SearchWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  & .collapse {
    margin-left: 1em;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  }
  .iconWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
  }
  & .searchIcon {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: white;
  }
  & .searchBox {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: 0.2s all;
    flex: 1;
    :focus-within {
      min-width: 300px;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #fff !important;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    }
  }
`;

export const Styled = {
  SearchWrapper
};
```

example work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sun-qhw0h

Comment: Your codesandbox example seems to work well for me (Google Chrome). Could you explain what is the desired behavior?

Comment: in my input it really works I speak in the div of my icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** A second, much better solution that also seems to work:

You can use the `.collapse:focus-within .iconWrap` selector. Works well on Chrome and Firefox.

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-rubin-7yer4

---

The other, more complicated solution:

1. I've changed the order of the icon div and the input in the markup. Then I've added a `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to the `.collapse` selector in the SCSS. This reverses the order of the elements bringing it back to what it was before.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Styled.SearchWrapper>
      <div className="collapse">
        <input
          className="searchBox"
          type="search"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Search..."
        />
        <div className="iconWrap">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="searchIcon" icon={faCoffee} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Styled.SearchWrapper>
  );
}
```

**(Notice how the iconWrap is now after the input.)**

2. This move allows us to use the `~` CSS selector, this selector selects elements preceded by something else, in this case we want the `.iconWrap` that is preceded by the `.searchBox:focus-within` element (notice the pseudoselector here).

```css
.searchBox:focus-within ~ .iconWrap {
    background: red;
}
```

This will turn the background of the iconWrap red whenever the searchBox has focus.

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-shadow-z1dvk (icon background turns red on focus).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sun-qhw0h It really worked thanks a lot
could you just give me a hand?

I am a little lost in relation to adding a transition when I increase the size input I don’t know where it can be unregulated

I also think that I could improve as I wrote the code with flex display
could you help me with this if i could improve on something to decrease this css size?

Comment: @gabriel for the first question: add `transition: 0.2s ease-in-out all;` to the .searchBox (or any other element).

Comment: @gabriel for the second question, the code isn't really that bad.

Comment: one thing that made me a little sad was having to give border radius to the icon and input wrapper

this is sounding a little ugly

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sun-qhw0h could you look at this example? with transition look div icon

Comment: @gabriel you can remove the border-radius and the background from the icon, like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-violet-c8m51 since the parent already has that set.

Comment: yeah look this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-mountain-l5vee the problem is on focus, div input and icon lost border radius on focus

Comment: @gabriel Adding `overflow: hidden;` to .collapse will solve the problem. The problem is caused by overflow from the child elements - when they're transparent there is no problem, having a background causes that to show up.

Comment: omg thanks <3

I was thinking that the problem was related to me increasing the size of my input only and not my div.

Comment: hello could you help me just one more time?

I'm trying to change the placeholder font color more unsuccessfully